# HotChocolate (GraphQL) dynamic schemas and filtering

Tags: graphql, azure-cosmosdb, hotchocolate

I'm using [HotChocolate](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/get-started) for our GraphQL server in .NET and CosmosDb as DB, which is a document database. Sorry for a long post...

In our Db we will have one part of the document that is different depending on product type. Lets say that one product type is "Shoes", and another is "Jackets".

```
// A product with type "Shoes"
{
    "id": "123",
    "productType": "Shoes",
    "specific": {
        "shoeSize": 4,
        "isSandal": true,      
    }
}

// A product with type "Jackets"
{
    "id": "888",
    "productType": "Jackets",
    "specific": {
       "fluffyness": 12,
       "backPrint" : "Gretzky 99" 
    }
}
```

It should be possible for a Content Editor in our system to add new product types and add new fields to it, *on a running system* (cms-style). This means that the schema should be created dynamically.

[This article](https://chillicream.com/blog/2021/09/27/hot-chocolate-12#dynamic-schemas) and the provided [github-project](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate-examples/tree/master/misc/TypeModules) describes creating new object types "on the fly", but I don't understand how to create inputfilters, so its also possible to query on the new fields. (It doesn't work, just trying to create a FilterInputTypeDefinition)

I have done a small experiment (not used the article way yet), adding the property "shoeSize". I extend the product type with shoeSize-property, that is stored a dictionary on the .NET-basetype.

```
public class ProductType : ObjectType<Product>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Product> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field("lengthInMeter").Resolve(context =>
        {
            Product parent = context.Parent<Product>();
            return parent.Specific.ContainsKey("shoeSize") ? parent.Specific["shoeSize"] : null;
        }).Type<IntType>();
    }
}
```

This works as expected and I can specify the lenghtInMeter as a field in my gql-query. What I cannot do is a query like this

```
getProducts(where : { shoeSize: {lg : 4}}) //using property shoeSize is not possible
```

, since the input type, doesnt have lengthInMeter, just the ProductType. How to I do that

in a hardcoded sense, ie inherit from FilterInputType
more importantly following the example in the link and also creating a filterinputtype with new fields.

Will this create a correct `IQueryable` that can be translated to a SQL for my database? If not: where can I intercept / take over that that `IQueryable` creation?

Comment: Did you resolve this - I too have an issue where I want to filter based on a resolved field but the federated schema just won't filter on fields that are either external or using resolvers :/

Comment: No, sorry. Nothing, contacted Hot Chocolate team in every possible way, nothing. This has been re-prioritized in our project. Hopefully we will not use HC at all

Comment: Sorry for the frustration @Cowborg we introduced some new APIs around 12.6 or so where you can now take over the IQueryable in a very simple way. Before you also could do it with a middleware. 

There are also now things like the type modules which we created for dynamic types.

Version 13 will allow more on the data mapping site. Its a big project and sometimes things take time. 

Did you create an issue? Can you post me the link?

Comment: If you are on our slack give me a ping https://slack.chillicream.com